# Make a password appear as *** in a prompt box in ASP.NET

Tags: passwords, prompt

I have some buttons that when the user clicks on those, a prompt box opens and gets the password of the user. The program works well, but I want that password to appear as `***` in the prompt, but I can not do it. How do I find a solution?

Comment: Try `<input type="password">`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you will want a password type input.

`<input type="password" />`